# Why are clean URLs not working when redirecting to https?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, drupal-6, clean-urls

I added some lines in my htacess file to redirect all http requests to https. Now when I type in a URL like: http://example.com/frames/view/4701362, it redirects to: https://example.com/index.php?q=frames/view/4701362. I can go to the page manually: https://example.com/frames/view/4701362 and the URL does not get changed.

I have Clean URLs set up

[image: Clean URLs configuration]

Htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  #some more stuff here, unrelated 

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

Edit:
I tried reversing the Drupal index.php?q= line and the https lines like this...

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But then my site did not load properly and said Page not found even at the homepage.

Comment: It looks like it's doing exactly what your rules say to do. Do you want it to behave differently?

Comment: If I type in _http://example.com/frames I want it to redirect to _https://example.com/frames NOT _https://example.com/index.php?q=frames (ignore the underscores)

Comment: The first rewrite rule is responsible for that change and the second does the HTTPS switch. It looks like you only need the second, so try eliminating the first.

Comment: I think that is something that Drupal puts in there

Comment: I actually think it needs to be switched around... HTTPS redirect first, then rewrite to index.php

Comment: I tried that (see my edit above), but then I got page not found on all my site (for any page)

Comment: Please check your browser's inspector (Network tab in Chrome) to see what redirects are taking place. (Be sure to select 'Preserve Log'.)

Comment: Before changing the htaccess file, this is what the network traffic looked like: _http://example.com/frames/ Response: Failed to load response data
_https://example.com/index.php?q=frames Response: Page is loaded. After changing the htacess file to put the https stuff first, I just got the one request: _http://example/frames/ Response: Page not found (ignore the underscores)

Comment: Ok, turns out you were pretty close to having the correct answer @MikeRockett, I just had to add [L,R=301] to the RewriteRule for https: RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MikeRockett above, I was able to figure this out. In addition to his suggestion, I had to add `[L,R=301]` to the RewriteRule line.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  #some more stuff here, unrelated 

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]  

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Indeed - that is correct. Though, I think only the `L` flag was required as a redirect is implied by specifying a full URL.